# Parse error: syntax error,

Tags: php, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вся ошибка возникает если только я начинаю использовать define но если на прямую писать как в php4 то ошибок не возникает. Сама ошибка выглядит так:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Z:\home\mysql.for\www\driver_connect_db.php on line 14 
Подскажите уважаемые специалисты - как это решить ?

Comment: Кто ж константы в кавычках использует!?

Comment: константы кавычек без надо ??

Comment: использование констант БЕЗ ковыче........... неужели ошибки читать не умете? Пишут же `=` у вас кому написано? ........... используете `mysqli`, а для `set names` почему-то `mysql`.........не ставьте вы `@` это неправильно!!! Боже, 10 строк, а сколько ужаса)

Comment: кавычки-то кавычками, но ошибка-то про знак равенства стоящий сразу после функции

Comment: @splash58 я это обозначил уже)

Comment: Еще перед return отсутствует точка с запятой ...

Comment: Насобирали корзиночку ошибок :-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, если брать все ошибки, то:

- использование констант происходит БЕЗ заключения их в кавычки
- в самом сообщении об ошибке написано, что неожиданно негаданно знак `=` откуда-то взялся после закрытой фигурной скобки. Надо его убрать.
- используете `mysqli`, но неожиданно для `set names` почему-то `mysql`
- не ставьте вы `@` - это неправильно!!! При возникновении грубых ошибок, сервер просто умолчит и вы будете очень долго и упорно искать место проблемы, а оно вон...заткнулось и молчит в тряпочку. Обрабатывайте проблемные места. `try catch`. Или еще какими-либо способами. Но не затыкайте рот серваку об ошибках. Кстати она еще, говорят, замедляет скрипт.
- перед `return` отсутствует точка с запятой

В более общем виде ВАШ код будет выглядеть пока так:

```
function connect_db() {
    $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, BASE);

    if (!$connect)
        die(mysqli_errno().' '.mysqli_error().' Ошибка подключения.');

    mysqli_query('SET NAMES urf8');
    mysqli_character_set_name('utf8');

    return $connect;
}
```

Comment: @ это вроде подавление ошибок

Comment: @LenovoID вы думаете хорошо подавлять ошибки таким способом? Их надо логировать.То, что сообщение об ошибке - исчезло  не значит, что проблема устранена.  Например, у Вас на сайте что-то перестало работать. И как Вы узнайте, где проблема? Ведь все ошибки подавляются. Её не рекомендуют уже давно и считают дурным тоном

Comment: я не спорю - спасибо за решение - я вчера сам доехал до этого ! ответил только сегодня спасибо